# Pine script series variables accessing last element

Tags: pine-script

I'm getting the `VWMA` output as a `series` type :

```
basis = vwma(src, length)
```

If I understand a `series` as an array, my question is simple how can I access the last element of `basis`?
I suppose that the last element is a float number!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Series is kinda arrays but not exactly. It will have individual values for each bar but its last value will always be used on each execution unless you specify otherwise.

So, when you use that variable, its last value will be used in the calculations.

To access the previous values, you can use the [History Reference Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator).

After you read that, you should understand that the following is the same thing.

```
basis = vwma(src, length)
plot(basis)
plot(basis[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference, now I have a clearer idea about the series, so basic[0] is also a series. So there is no way to get the last element (in array sens) ? What I need is the last position (its Y value which the price) of plot(basis).

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Just use `basis` as it is and its last value at that bar will be used.

Comment: Yes got it, thank you.

Comment: Hopefully the TV developers will include some sort of function to isolate any given value from a series.

Comment: @carloswm85, I suggest you have a look at [pinescript execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html#:~:text=Pine%20Script%E2%84%A2%20strategies%20will,a%20limited%20number%20of%20bars.). This idea sounds reasonable but does not really make any sense once you understand how it all works.